# C# New window focus

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c#-express-2010

My program contains a listview with "SelectionChanged" event. When I'm changing the selected item in the list view I want to open a new window with specific options related to it. But the problem is that the new window appears for a moment and it hides behind the main window. 
This is a part of my code:

```
private void display_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var editwindow = new EditWindow();
        editwindow.Show();
        editwindow.Focus();
    }
```

I've also include Focus function in second window when it's initiated. How I could solve this problem?

Comment: Which GUI toolkit does this refer to? WPF? WinForms? Please add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to change the focus *while* an event is fired is often troublesome, it is here.  You'd need a PostSelectionChanged event but that's not available.  You can create your own though, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() can run the target after all the event processing is completed.  This solves your problem:

```
private void display_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
       var editwindow = new EditWindow();
       editwindow.Show();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Activate() function:

```
editWindow.Activate();
```